# AlertDialog before selecting checkBox in Android

Tags: android, checkbox, android-alertdialog, confirmation

I have dialog with checkBox. Before selecting this checkBox i would like to ask user, that he is sure to select these checkBox. (I mean, I try to select checkBox and before this AlertDialog appear and ask whether I am sure)

In code it looks like this:

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.favouriteChkBox);

            if (cb.isChecked()) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context);
                builder.setTitle("Do you want to add this to favourite?");

                builder.setPositiveButton("yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                itemChecked.set(position, true);
                            }
                        });
                builder.setNegativeButton("no",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                builder.create().show();

            }
```

But this does not work. The AlertDialog is shown and no metter if I clicked "yes" or "no", checkBox is selected.

Can you tell me why this does not work?
Thanks!

Comment: You should be setting the checkbox's checked state to false when the user clicks "no". Since you are simply just canceling the alertdialig, the checkbox is still in the check state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.favouriteChkBox);

    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (cb.isChecked()) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        TestGitActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Do you want to add this to favourite?");

                builder.setPositiveButton("yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                cb.setChecked(true);
                            }
                        });
                builder.setNegativeButton("no",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                cb.setChecked(false);
                            }
                        });
                builder.create().show();

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks: @Siddharth Lele, moncadad, StinePike for hints.Unfortunately, it works only partially correct. At the time of pressing the checkbox, this checkbox is already selected or deselected, and AlertDialog only revoke the changes.

I would like to have:  At the time of pressing the checkbox, the AlertDialog is called and there is made decision: select/diselect checkbox. I have checked a few Listner, but they don't work as I wish.

Comment: I think, then you should create a custom check box. or you can simply use a toggle button (or even button) with two state. in normal and active state use similar checked/unchecked image on the button. Then you can easily handle the button by yourself

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this has to with the fact that if the User chooses **NO**, the state of the `CheckBox` is not being changed in the `OnClickListener` for the `NegativeButton`.
Try this code:

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.favouriteChkBox);
if (cb.isChecked()) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Do you want to add this to favourite?");

    builder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            itemChecked.set(position, true);
            // ADD THIS TO YOUR CODE
            cb.setChecked(true);
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("no", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // ADD THIS TO YOUR CODE
            .setChecked(false);
            dialog.dismiss(); // CHANGE THE .cancel() TO dismiss()
        }
    });

    builder.create().show();
}
```